# Addition and subtraction using HTML5 and either JS or ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, razor

I'm trying to set up a very, *very* basic page on my localhost to add and subtract values.

I've got a web page set up in ASP.NET Razor to do this. Problem is, I'm rather inexperienced at web application development. Microsoft's vast (and often contradictory) array of documentation isn't really helping, and I might lack the fundamental understanding of what I'm trying to do. That being in mind, don't crucify me here.

I want to have three fields: a first value, a second value, and a result output. I have two buttons that will select either addition or subtraction, along with another button to make the operation happen (a submit button, if you will). Obviously, these items are in HTML. Now, I need to do the operation. Which language would I use to do this operation: ASP.NET/Razor C# ("server" side) or JavaScript ("browser" side)? I assume there are ways to do both, but I'm somewhat murky on how it would be accomplished in either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do both - but talking you through how to implement this in either, whilst simple, has too many pre-requisites for a StackOverflow question. JavaScript probably presents the lowest barrier to entry, but if you understand enough to get a page down to the user already - it shouldn't be too hard to create a view model with the required data and do the addition or subtraction in a controller action using C#.

The outline workflow in JavaScript is-

1. Find the inputs in the page by ID, name or class (ID is easiest for beginners as it has a simple long-standing API)
2. Get the values of the inputs - you will probably want to assign these to variables, but if you have references to the DOM elements you could work directly with the value from those.
3. Check that the values are in fact numbers and not strings or other values which you cannot perform mathematical operations on.
4. Determine the operation to be carried out. A simple option would be to have a variable on the page holding an initial state, and either toggle it with presses of the same button or change it with presses (clicks) of addition and subtraction buttons as described.
5. Use a conditional statement ("if" would be simplest for a two option situation like yours) to carry out the desired arithmetic operation on the values. Assign the result to a variable.
6. Create a new element to contain the answer and add it to the page, or modify the text of an existing page element.

The above would need to be done in an event handler function that responds to a click event on the result button.

Further learning resources-

- https://www.codeschool.com/
- http://www.codecademy.com/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/

For ASP.NET MVC/Razor-

1. Submit the form to a controller action
2. The controller action will either need to accept a view model as a parameter, or separate parameters that represent the numbers to be added and the operation.
3. Use a conditional statement to perform the desired operation in C# - adding or subtracting the values. Assign the result to a variable.
4. Pass the variable to a view to display the data.
5. Return the view result or partial result to the user (use partial only if submitting the request via Ajax and showing the result in a modal window - this is too advanced for now).

Further learning resources-

- http://www.asp.net/mvc
- http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably know this, but this question is incredibly broad.  I'll try to supply a simple answer to *one* of your questions ("server side or browser"):

I'd probably go server side, that way you don't have to depend on your users having JS enabled.  However, if you know your users have JS and/or you don't care, then JS will be faster since it won't have to go hit the server again.

As to how you implement, I'd say that's outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your question is *very* broad and the choice of means to achieve your task really depends on many factors. Anyway, I wrote down this, rather primitive, version of what I think you want to perform in JavaScript and jQuery, so it is all happening on client side:

```
<script>
function addOperands() {
    var result = $('#operand1').val() + $('#operand2').val();
    $('#result').val(result);
}

function subtractOperands() {
    var result = $('#operand1').val() - $('#operand2').val();
    $('#result').val(result);
}
</script>

<input id="operand1" type="number" value="5"/>
<input id="operand2" type="number" value="6"/>
<input id="result" type="number" disabled/>
<button id="add" onclick="addOperands()">Add</button>
<button id="subtract" onClick="subtractOperands()">Subtract</button>
```

You can try it out in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cneusceb/).